# Terminal recognizes old git account want change to new git account

Tags: git, github, terminal

I had a school git account i used for school projects. I recently created a personal account on my personal email vs my school. Is there a way to reconfigure this on terminal. This is the error I am getting

```
MacBook-Pro:Projects user$ git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to user/repo.git denied to newuser.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user/repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Comment: There's really no such thing as a "git account", nor is your git client configured with one.  You configure your email address, but that is only used for commits, and has nothing to do with remote authentication. `git` uses authentication helpers for doing this authentication, but you haven't told us if you're using one or not.

Comment: the remote is what i get in the error message. I do a clone https://github.com/user/repo.git/ then created a test file and tried a test commit. How would I configure the email address for my personal account?

Comment: I'd recommend [setting up ssh keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) for the account. You'll want to set the remote to use ssh as well then rather than https.